# [Angular]How to declare a function inside a button which is in external JS file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="generate()">Draw</button>
```

When i click "Draw" the function `generate()` is not found.
But i defined `generate()` inside external javascript file.Like below

```
<script src="../circle.js"></script>
```

When on run it shows as generate not defined in console.
Please Help Me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use it directly in Angular as a component or Module.

insert your function into the  .component.ts, and call it from it's .component.html file.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare that function and include your file in html and that function will automatically resolved at run time:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
declare function generate() : void;
```

Import your

```
<script src="../circle.js"></script>
```

file in your Main HTML File where angular app is loading generally index.html